# How to save output table within the DB

Tags: mysql

I run a computation query and displayed an output table, instead of exporting it as csv file, i want is to save it or make it another table within my DB, is it possible?

Comment: yes. it is possible.

Comment: can you show me the script?

Comment: I am sorry this is not a script writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can..
Create a table first to your database. 
Then write a query to insert data to your created table.

```
$getTheDataFromYourPrevQuery = //set your data here
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (name)"." VALUES('$getTheDataFromYourPrevQuery')";
    try {
        $db = $this->db;
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->execute();
        //$user->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($user); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
```

Comment: is this for MySql?